# Is there a difference between (i) and (int(i)

Tags: python, casting, floating-point

Can someone explain this code to me and why it prints what it prints

```
def the_decimal(i):
    if i - int(i) != 0:
        return i - int(i)
    else:
        return 'INTEGER' 


print(the_decimal(99.1))
print(the_decimal(99.0))
```

Comment: What specific line are you unclear about? It is basically checking if the `float` has any non-zero decimal value, if not it is numerically equivalent to an integer.

Comment: Do you understand that calling `int` on a floating point number returns the integer part?  So `int(99.1)` returns 99.  `int(99.0)` returns 99 also.  Even though 99.0 is a floating point number, it has an integer value.

Comment: @zenmaster777 Welcome to SO. Please read [type casting in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp) for details on what you want to understand. Since this is too basic and general a question for Stack overflow, I am **voting to close**.

Comment: i think the point you are trying to make its about 'print(99.1 - 99)' ---> 0.09999999999999432 and not 0.1 as in non computing world

Comment: try -->   return round((i - int(i)),2)

Answer (score 2):

Two things are happening:

1. The 99.1 is being implicitly cast as a float which is imprecise by design leading to the repeated decimal output (In Python3.8 I get 0.09999999999999432
2. The subtraction is between a decimal and that decimal's integer representation (essentially rounding to a whole number) which, of course, won't equal zero.

So while number 2 is pretty obvious because `99.1 - 99 <> 0`, number 1 is due to the implicit casting to a float leading to the odd output, where one would expect to just see 0.1.

To see this yourself you can toss in `print(type(i))` up in the function:

```
def the_decimal(i):
    print(type(i))
    if i - int(i) != 0:
        return i - int(i)
    else:
        return 'INTEGER' 

print(the_decimal(99.1))
print(the_decimal(99.0))
```

---

```
<class 'float'>
0.09999999999999432
<class 'float'>
INTEGER
```

For more information about the type casting of numbers you check out [this page](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/type-conversion-and-casting)

Comment: Thankyou all for your help. My misunderstanding came from not knowing calling the int returns the integer even on a float. I understand the computation now.